# WP_Query shows wrong result for queries that user not logged in

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have some issue to load posts from widgets using ajax ,I have this code in my own widget to fetch some posts:

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat' => $catID
);
$q = new WP_Query($query_args);
while($q->have_posts()){
    $q->the_post();
    the_title();
}
wp_reset_query();
```

And this code in **mysidebar.php**

```
<div>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('mysidebar'); ?>
</div>
```

In wordpress admin I drag and drop 4 widget in mysidebar with **different category ID**.

At last register a ajax function like blow:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_itr", "itr");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_itr", "itr");
function itr() {
    require 'path/to/mysidebar.php';
    wp_die();
}
```

This is my jquery code to load mysidebar.php data:

```
$.post(ajaxurl, {
   action : "itr"
   }, function (data, status) {
       // Success Response ...
       if (status === "success") {
          $("#the_id").html(data);
       }
   }
});
```

**What is the problem?** the problem is when user not logged in, wp_query return wrong posts! Its load some posts for all categories!

**Note**: There is no private or protected post

Comment: You mean it work fine when user is logged in ?

Comment: @cjmling yes ...

Comment: when using ajax make sure you hook *no_prev* as well https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side